# HttpURLConnection RequestPropertys are null

Tags: java, http, url

I am trying to connect my java app to a public game API at https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/

for this i have written below code:

```
url = new URL(URL_PREFIX + "account");

HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

String authent = "Bearer ".concat(API_KEY);

//Authorization
con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authent);
con.addRequestProperty("Authorization", authent);
System.out.println(con.getRequestProperty("Authorization")); //null
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

I am getting http 400 error  and i think it is because the authorization property is not set. Why am I getting null for `getRequestProperty`?

Comment: This URL is HTTPS, you may need to use `HttpsURLConnection`

Comment: i tried it out sitll the same erros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a thread on the guildwars forum say that they have internal issue, 
[Review that](https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/community/api/API-Keys-ErrBadData-since-patch/first#post5272812) :).

**Lawton Campbell

 Web Programmer**

> I posted a note in our internal chat
>   about it being broken, but yeah, it’s the weekend so it’s probably not
>   gonna be fixed before Monday. Really sorry about that

Comment: How is password authentication helping, when the api needs bearer tokens?

Comment: i tried        `con.setRequestProperty("Host",URL_PREFIX);`    but still the same problem

Comment: have a look on the answer